# set actionbar sherlock to bottom

Tags: android

i created the native tab bar in android using phonegap but i can't able to move to bottom.

I want the solution for my question:

How to set actionbarsherlock tab bar to bottom in android using phonegap?

Answer (score 3):

> How to set actionbarsherlock tab bar to bottom in android using phonegap?

AFAIK, this is not supported by ActionBarSherlock, let alone by whatever plugin you are using. It also goes against the [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

Comment: Please don't put your navigation components on the bottom of the screen.  Follow standards!